# 復数のプロセスを持つデーモンの作り方

Tags: python, linux

python でかかれた一定時間ごとに実行したい復数の処理を
１つの起動スクリプトでデーモン化したいです

```
def a():
  while True:
    sleep(10)
    print('a')
```

```
def b():
  while True:
    sleep(10)
    print('b')
```

start_daemon.py

```
  while True:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        pid_file = open('/var/run/a.pid', 'w')
        pid_file.write(str(pid)+"\n")
        pid_file.close()
        break
    if pid == 0:
        a()

  while True:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        pid_file = open('/var/run/b.pid', 'w')
        pid_file.write(str(pid)+"\n")
        pid_file.close()
        break
    if pid == 0:
        b()
```

こんな感じで２つ並べれば起動はするんですが
pid ファイルが復数できてしまうのでサービスファイルをどうかけばいいかわかりませんし
当たり前ですがプロセスも両方きらないと落とせません

ウェブサーバーなんかだとマスタープロセスが子プロセスを復数生み出すようになってて
マスターをkillすれば子プロセスは全部死ぬとおもうんですが
python script の復数のメソッドをそんな感じにするにはどうすればいいんでしょうか

Comment: 検索でこんなのが引っ掛かりましたが調べてみては？[Supervisorの使用方法](https://www.task-notes.com/entry/20170311/1489224418)

Comment: pythonスクリプトを [daemonize](https://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize) で実行させて、それを cron に登録しておくとか。

Comment: > Supervisorの使用方法　みてみたのですが１つのプログラムをデーモン化するのがPID管理とか簡単になるというだけで１回の起動で２つのタイマーループを動かしたいという質問内容に関して結局どうしたらいいかよくわかりません

Comment: > cron　が使えれば簡単だったんですが秒単位の制御がしたくて方法がわからなかったので自前でsleepで実現しようとしてます

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`start_daemon.py` は子プロセスを2つ作ったあと終了しようとしていますが、子プロセスを管理する必要があります。

systemd等のサービスマネージャーには、この `start_daemon.py` のPIDを管理させます。
サービスマネージャーから停止させるときは、 `start_daemon.py` にTERMシグナルを送信して、 `start_daemon.py` は [signal.signal](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal)でTERMシグナルをハンドリングして、TERMシグナルが届いたら、2つの子プロセスのPIDに同様にTERMシグナルを送信して停止させてください。

---

実際の実装はエラーハンドリングなども含めてもうすこし複雑になると思います。
定期的に処理を実行するライブラリ [APScheduler](https://pypi.org/project/APScheduler/) を利用したり、そもそもPythonで定期実行を管理せずにサービスマネージャーに定期的に実行させる方法などもあります。systemdであれば、systemd.timerを設定すればよいと思います。

Comment: なるほどです。イメージは掴めました。親プロセス自体もデーモン化してシグナルを見張って子プロセスに伝達するわけですね。「TERMシグナルが届いたら、」の部分がどうやればいいかわからないですがしらべてやってみます！